# Doesn't work execute arguments

Tags: powershell

I write  powershell script, which extract files from sharepoint installation. When I execute this script, I see fileDialog, in which I need choose path.

```
$path="C:\Script\Download\SharePointServer.exe " 
$arguments = "/extract "
start-process $path  $arguments -wait -verb runas
```

But when I execute this script, I see error: Usage: /extract:path, extract the content of the package...

```
$path="C:\Script\Download\SharePointServer.exe " 
$arguments = "/extract ""C:\Script\Download"""
start-process $path  $arguments -wait -verb runas
```

So how it's fix?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
$path="C:\Script\Download\SharePointServer.exe"
$arguments = "/extract C:\Script\Download"
& $path $arguments;
```

Hope it works ;)